# how to fetch a complex substring using qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qregularexpression

I am working my hands on QT and c++. As part of a test project, i need fetch a substring from a complex and long string, basically it is a source of a webpage. If my question looks very trivial then it would be because i am a naive qt programmer and have less experience of regular expressions.

**String:**
"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map":"type=video%2Fwebm%3B+codecs%3D%22vp8.0%2C+vorbis%22\u0026quality=medium\u0026itag=43\u0026url=**https%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-ci5gup-qxaz.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fmime%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%26key%3Dyt6%26initcwndbps%3D386250%26pcm2cms%3Dyes%26requiressl%3Dyes%26signature%3D05FB41F2F9FF5490841C7B9F40748FC4B8F505A3.0D81AB0745519F179CBF4468D2412C2240DC72F0%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26fexp%3D3300119%252C3300131%252C3313268%252C9405961%252C9416126%252C9416891%252C9419451%252C9422342%252C9422596%252C9427790%252C9428398%252C9431012%252C9433096%252C9433380%252C9433855%252C9433946%252C9434332%252C9435526%252C9435667%252C9435876%252C9436270%252C9436607%252C9436834%252C9436872%252C9436973%252C9437066%252C9437553%252C9437742%252C9438326%252C9439652%252C9439979%252C9440048%252C9440552%252C9440651%26ms%3Dau%26mt%3D1467900993%26sparams%3Ddur%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpcm2cms%252Cpl%252Cratebypass%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26mv%3Dm%26ip%3D182.68.203.45%26id%3Do-AMB0Fggb71vKhXSdQqcOPdLeb9v0n2GaibsWg_W5L5b7%26mm%3D31%26mn%3Dsn-ci5gup-qxaz%26upn%3Dfri9F8GP9uA%26source%3Dyoutube%26itag%3D43%26pl%3D20%26lmt%3D1445550849945309%26expire%3D1467922869%26sver%3D3%26ipbits%3D0%26dur%3D0.000,type=video%2Fmp4%3B+codecs%3D%22avc1.42001E%2C+mp4a.40.2%22**\u0026quality=medium\u0026itag=18\u0026url=**https%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-ci5gup-qxaz.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fmime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26key%3Dyt6%26initcwndbps%3D386250%26pcm2cms%3Dyes%26requiressl%3Dyes%26signature%3D4C90C634F68098572BDCA7D5B7946F8A49A17369.D4AB7172922F499596226BA335BDF0B4519A4AC6%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26fexp%3D3300119%252C3300131%252C3313268%252C9405961%252C9416126%252C9416891%252C9419451%252C9422342%252C9422596%252C9427790%252C9428398%252C9431012%252C9433096%252C9433380%252C9433855%252C9433946%252C9434332%252C9435526%252C9435667%252C9435876%252C9436270%252C9436607%252C9436834%252C9436872%252C9436973%252C9437066%252C9437553%252C9437742%252C9438326%252C9439652%252C9439979%252C9440048%252C9440552%252C9440651%26ms%3Dau%26mt%3D1467900993%26sparams%3Ddur%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpcm2cms%252Cpl%252Cratebypass%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26mv%3Dm%26ip%3D182.68.203.45%26id%3Do-AMB0Fggb71vKhXSdQqcOPdLeb9v0n2GaibsWg_W5L5b7%26mm%3D31%26mn%3Dsn-ci5gup-qxaz%26upn%3Dfri9F8GP9uA%26source%3Dyoutube%26itag%3D18%26pl%3D20%26lmt%3D1465194153116908%26expire%3D1467922869%26sver%3D3%26ipbits%3D0%26dur%3D207.354,type=video%2F3gpp%3B+codecs%3D%22mp4v.20.3%2C+mp4a.40.2%22**\u0026quality=small\u0026itag=36\u0026url=

Above string is a big part of my complete string and similar pattern. This webpage source have many encoded urls which i need to seperate. below is what i am trying to seperate.

**SubString:**

https%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-ci5gup-qxaz.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fmime%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%26key%3Dyt6%26initcwndbps%3D386250%26pcm2cms%3Dyes%26requiressl%3Dyes%26signature%3D05FB41F2F9FF5490841C7B9F40748FC4B8F505A3.0D81AB0745519F179CBF4468D2412C2240DC72F0%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26fexp%3D3300119%252C3300131%252C3313268%252C9405961%252C9416126%252C9416891%252C9419451%252C9422342%252C9422596%252C9427790%252C9428398%252C9431012%252C9433096%252C9433380%252C9433855%252C9433946%252C9434332%252C9435526%252C9435667%252C9435876%252C9436270%252C9436607%252C9436834%252C9436872%252C9436973%252C9437066%252C9437553%252C9437742%252C9438326%252C9439652%252C9439979%252C9440048%252C9440552%252C9440651%26ms%3Dau%26mt%3D1467900993%26sparams%3Ddur%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpcm2cms%252Cpl%252Cratebypass%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26mv%3Dm%26ip%3D182.68.203.45%26id%3Do-AMB0Fggb71vKhXSdQqcOPdLeb9v0n2GaibsWg_W5L5b7%26mm%3D31%26mn%3Dsn-ci5gup-qxaz%26upn%3Dfri9F8GP9uA%26source%3Dyoutube%26itag%3D43%26pl%3D20%26lmt%3D1445550849945309%26expire%3D1467922869%26sver%3D3%26ipbits%3D0%26dur%3D0.000,type=video%2Fmp4%3B+codecs%3D%22avc1.42001E%2C+mp4a.40.2%22

Please help and suggest as how can i do that using QT, C++, regular expressions. I Do not wish to use any other programming language.
Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) class for working with strings in Qt. You should study `QString` documentation sections: `Manipulating String Data` and `Querying String Data`. Maybe, [contains()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#contains) method of `QString` class is enough for solve your problem.

**UPD:**

Simple example with substring manipulating:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString bigString = "BigString BigString SubString BigString";
    QString subString = "SubString";

    bool containsFlag = bigString.contains(subString, Qt::CaseSensitive);
    int index = bigString.indexOf(subString, 0, Qt::CaseSensitive);

    qDebug() << "Length of subString: " << subString.length();
    qDebug() << "SubString contains in bigString: " << containsFlag;
    qDebug() << "SubString index in bigString: " << index;

    return a.exec();
}
```

As you can see, you can determine if `subString` contains in `bigString`. Of course, you can determine index of `subString` in `bigString`.
You can put your own data in `bigString` and `subString`.

Comment: Hi Kirill, Can you please help me out with little more on this perticular problem. Actually most part of this string is variable. I am certain only about start and beginning of sub-string.